# Where are the bech32 binaries?

Tags: bech32

Hi I am trying to convert from hex to bech32.
This repo says that there is a tool which can do this and that the binaries can be found at cardano-wallet releases, however I cannot find them there.  The readme also gives no instructions on how to build the binaries from source. https://github.com/input-output-hk/bech32#usage  Where can I find these binaries?

Comment: Hi guys. For anyone who is a dingus like me (unlikely).  they are in the .tar.gz file.  I was confused because they are not present in the zip file

Answer (score 1):

bech32 binaries/cli commands come preinstalled with cardano-wallet software. If you follow the instructions to install `cardano-wallet`, you'll be able to use `bech32` commands from the same executable path (the same is true for `cardano-addresses`).

Alternatively, if you really don't want to install cardano-wallet, you can download the bech32 binaries [here](https://github.com/input-output-hk/bech32).

Comment: so I found the binaries, but jsuk  I have cardano-wallet installed.  v2022-01-18 (git revision: a5085acbd2670c24251cf8d76a4e83c77a2679ba).

i can call cardano-wallet, but the binaries were not automatically added